# How to enumerate users when switching users on Windows Server 2022?

Tags: users, windows-server-2022

After Microsoft pushed an update, users cannot be enumerated when switching users, and the user name must be entered every time. I have multiple users on my computer that need to be switched frequently, is there a way to restore this user enumeration feature?

Comment: Does this help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/180091/windows-10-logon-show-multiple-accounts-on-logon-s.html

Comment: @JG7 Useless. I set up all the configurations mentioned in it, and there is no change.